# How to access a UIButton or a UILabel in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with 20 rows. In each row, two `UIButton`s are added, so totally I have 40 buttons. How can I access each button in each cell? All those `UIButton` have the two `tag`s 1 and 2.

For example: I want to write a method to change the background color of 2 buttons in a particular row:

```
-(void)changeColor:(int)row{
     //code here
}
```

Do you have any suggestion?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];
        UIButton *button1=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x1,y1,w1,h1)];
        UIButton *button2=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x2,y2,w2,h2)];       
        [button1 setTag:1];
        [button2 setTag:2];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:button0 ];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:button1 ];
        [button0  release];
        [button1  release];        
    }
    UIButton *button1  = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UIButton *button2  = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Where do you need to grab a reference of the button? Have you tried this? `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];`

Comment: Note that you can have 20 rows of data but may not have 20 unique cells...depending on how many are displayed at one time.  That's part of the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
-changeColor:(int)row
{
    NSIndexPath indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]; // Assuming one section
    UITableViewCell *cell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIButton *button1 = (UIButton *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:1];
    UIButton *button2 = (UIButton *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:2];
}
```

*some syntax might be wrong. I dont have Xcode handy

Comment: I used your code to change the buttons in first row, but it change button in both first row and 5th row. Do you know why?

Comment: It has to do with what Phillip Mills said about not necessarily having 20 unique cells. At some point in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method `cell != nil` and was reused.  I would do 1 of two things: 1)remove `if(cell == nil)` and `init` the cell every time or 2)assign a unique tag to each button (ie indexPath.row + 100 for button1 and indexPath.row + 200 for button2) so that each button on each row is unique (pretty much what rdelmar said)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the button color to have a highlighted / downstate I suggest to use the following:

```
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchCancel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];

-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [self touchCancel:sender];
    /* DO SOME MORE ACTIONS */
}

-(void)changeColor:(UIButton*)sender
{
    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

-(void)touchCancel:(UIButton*)sender
{
    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

---

If you want to make the button have a different selected color, create an array that holds all the selected states. Then use the array to check if the button color needs a different color in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

When you want to change the button color just change the value in the array and call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Be sure to do it outside the if (cell == nil) method so it is also called when the cell is reused.